# Nested Scoped Slots Variable Collisions VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I've created a simple scoped slot component that I need to nest, but I'm struggling to figure out how I can avoid naming collisions.

Vue Component nested-fields

```
<script>
export default {
    props: [ 
        "entityName",
        "items"
    ],
  data: function() {
    return {
        formItems: this.items
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
        this.items.push({})
    },
    removeItem: function(index) {
        if (this.items[index].id) {
            this.$set(this.items[index], '_destroy', true);
        } else {
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="nested-fields">
        <div v-show="item._destroy !== true || typeof item._destroy == 'undefined'" class="card nested-fields__field-set mb-2" v-for="(item, index) in formItems" :key="index">
            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span>Add {{entityName}}</span> <span class="fa fa-times" @click="removeItem(index)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <slot name='item-fields' v-bind="{item, index}"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb-2" type="button" @click="addItem()">Add {{entityName}}</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

HTML

```
    <nested-fields entity-name="Rotap Analysis" :items="[]">
        <template #item-fields="{item, index}"> 
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label>
                    Amount (g)
                    <input type="number" min="0" v-model="item.amount_grams" :name="'setup[input_material_attributes][rotap_analysis_attributes]['+index+'][amount_grams]'" class="form-control">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            </div>

            <nested-fields entity-name="Sieve" :items="[]">
                <template #item-fields="{item2, index2}">   
                    <label>
                        Sieve Size (US Mesh)
                        <input type="number" min="0" v-model="item2.size_mesh" :name="'setup[input_material_attributes][rotap_analysis_attributes]['+index+'][rotap_sieves]['+index2+'][size_mesh]'" class="form-control">
                    </label>
                </template>
            </nested-fields>
        </template>
    </nested-fields>
```

I need to rename the variables in the nested template shown here:

```
<nested-fields entity-name="Sieve" :items="item.rotap_sieves || []">
    <!-- this line --><template #item-fields="{item2, index2}">
```

So I can use them here:

```
<input type="number" min="0" v-model="item2.size_mesh" :name="'setup[input_material_attributes][rotap_analysis_attributes]['+index+'][rotap_sieves]['+index2+'][size_mesh]'" class="form-control">
```

... BUT it does not let me rename the destructuring as I have it from "item" and "index" to "item2" and "index2".

For what it's worth, I'm attempting to replace Cocoon rails gem for nesting forms in my Rails app, though that shouldn't really matter.

Question - How can I rename the variables in nested scoped slots to avoid variable collisions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it's a simple destructuring syntax solution:

```
<template #item-fields="{item: item2, index: index2}">
```

Works perfectly as expected!